# How to know what type of encryption type is that?

Tags: encryption, hash, encoding

the hash is a lot of numbers separated by hyphens, something like that
02-35-161-51-43-227-161-06-151-43-22-71-43-46-21....
More than 700 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you have displayed so far do fall within the confines of an [ASCII table](https://theasciicode.com.ar/), you could start there.